# Not able to access Gitlab env variables either in node.js or react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, gitlab

I have two different projects checked in Gitlab, frontend and backend.
For both the projects i have a Dockerfile each. 
I have set the env variables in gitlab ci/cd .
I am running docker container in kubernetes, 
but i am not able to access the gitlab env variables either in my react or node.js (express) application.

I was thinking that those env variable would be available to me when i do process.env.variable_name, but i am not able to access them.

What’s the best way to access Gitlab env variables in kubernetes (deployment.yaml) env variables ?

**UPDATE**

I have found that we can specify env variables in kubernetes, deployment.yaml file (under env section). How can i pass gitlab env variables to deployment.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers require that you set environment variables when you run them:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

```
--env , -e      Set environment variables
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access environment variable in Node js application using Gitlab `K8S_SECRET_` variable naming convention.
For example define a variable like `K8S_SECRET_MY_TEST_API` in gitlab.
In Node js, you can access this variable using `process.env.MY_TEST_API`.

Only issue I am facing is that those variables are not available in React app. Still trying to figure that out. I will update here once I resolve that issue.

Comment: Just realized its 1 year old post. If you know the answer to my issue please respond here.

Answer (score 1):

To inject environment variables to a react app created with create-react-app you should add the prefix REACT_APP_ to every env var.

During the build, webpack will pick all the environment variables with that prefix and will add them to environment.